# Microsoft.Expression.Drawing.Aero missing (what is it?!)

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, window

I have a window and I created a "callout" there. When I try to create the new window with `this.InitializeComponent();` I get an exception:

> The assembly with display name 'Microsoft.Expression.Drawing.Aero' failed to load in the 'Load' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 1. The cause of the failure was: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Expression.Drawing.Aero, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

How can it be? What is Microsoft.Expression.Drawing.Aero?

Comment: I am having the same problem and realized it is project specific. I can start a new project and have no problem. I deleted my suo to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

The solution can be **delete your *.suo file*** and ReBuild your entire solution.

The *.suo file is found in the project root folder.(If you can't see your *.suo file be sure you have configured the windows explorer to see hidden files.)

Answer (score 0):

That is part of the Expression Blend SDK and means that some part of the project has been built via Expression from MS - [the SDK itself is AFAIK a free download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=75e13d71-7c53-4382-9592-6c07c6a00207). Just download and install it to resolve the described situation.

Comment: I already installed it... and still I got the same error. it looks like I need to use Microsoft.Expression.Drawing.controls and not aero.. but it still isnt working

Comment: @user1032412 Did you add it to the references in your project ?

Comment: @user1032412 Then set it to "copy local" in the project settings

Comment: copy local is set to true.. I dont understand what is  "Microsoft.Expression.Drawing.Aero" what is this aero?! there isnt such thing in the dll

Comment: The .Aero may have been appended (assuming your running on Windows 7 for example) because it was looking for the external theme assembly (i.e. the assembly that has the xaml used for that OS theme which happens because the main assembly's ThemeInfo attrib is set such that the non-generic xaml is external which MS typically does) although I'm surprised that would result in an unhandled exception.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I cannot tell you exactly what did it, but I ran a full purge on non-sourced files and it now works....So, it wasn't the suo, but it was something...

Answer (score 0):

I am just making wild guess. Since the exception is thrown while initializing the `Window` I assume that the application is trying to load the `Aero` theme from your machine (I guess Windows 7). See if there is any style defined for the windows which asks it to use `Aero` theme irrespective of the theme set being used by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing Expression Blend SDK (that Dll is part of it)?

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=75e13d71-7c53-4382-9592-6c07c6a00207

Comment: In my case, it took a full repository wipe, so it wasnt something missing

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multiple project in single solution, this exception will occurs. I removed my project from solution and ran it separately it works.