# A nonexistent .Aero assembly is referenced by WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, aero

I have a problem with `XamDataChart` in a WPF application. When I add the chart to the page the designer works ok, I set everything up and it looks ok on screen. Then I start the application and the chart constructor crashes the app looking for a non-existent assembly. This happens in both debug and release builds.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred
Message=Could not load file or assembly 'InfragisticsWPF4.DataVisualization.v11.1.Aero, Version=11.1.20111.2094, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
...
Calling assembly : PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
```

Callstack (relevant parts):

```
mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName
mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad
mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.Assembly.Load
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.SystemResources.ResourceDictionaries.LoadExternalAssembly
... 
InfragisticsWPF4.DataVisualization.v11.1.dll!Infragistics.InteractiveControl.InteractiveControl()   InfragisticsWPF4.DataVisualization.v11.1.dll!Infragistics.Controls.XamZoombar.XamZoombar()
InfragisticsWPF4.Controls.Charts.XamDataChart.v11.1.dll!Infragistics.Controls.Charts.XamDataChart.XamDataChart()
System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.Schema.XamlTypeInvoker.CreateInstance
```

Since I doubt that Infragistics ships their assemblies with unresolved references and I could not find the `.Aero` assembly anywhere on HDD I imagine this is some dynamic assembly loading done by PresentationFramework "on behalf" of control's assembly. I'm still not that good in WPF and I do not really understand this mechanism nor why the WPF tries to load this assembly nor why is it so important that WPF cannot fail gracefully. Can someone please shed some light on this and help me resolve this impasse.

Comment: Have you already tried to contact Infragistics for support? What was their response?

Comment: Thats my next step :) SO is usually faster :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, since your application is a WPF one and it tries to integrate with current theme in windows or current theme of your application, it searches for this .Aero dll since you are using Aero theme. You need to locate this dll and add the your project or changing your theme may be a workaround.

Comment: but there is no assembly with this name.

Comment: can you have a look at your resource files whether they include something related to aero theme?

Comment: Also, can you run the project in release mode? have a look, http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/p/67013/340465.aspx

Comment: I saw that post, but I get the exception in release mode as well. If I at least understood the mechanics behind WPF ending up needing this assembly maybe I could fond a workaround. Besides, I need to debug this app, their suggestion "run in lrelease mode" is lame

Comment: I do agree, have you tried changing your theme and debugging? If it works this way, then it may be concluded that it is totally related to the theme your machine working on.

Comment: well, my resource files do not reference anything in Aero, though it may happen to be the default theme. The thing is I use quite a lot of other infragistics controls across the app and only datachart instantiation raises the error.

Comment: I have a feeling that somehow datachart control does not support aero theme.

Comment: You were right, I can;t fix that so I just wrapped the exception and ignored it and the chart still initialized enough to show. Poor mans solution but best I have right now.

Answer (score 1):

For me the answer was to delete my **.suo** file and **ReBuild** my entire solution. As suggested by one of the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028429/microsoft-expression-drawing-aero-missing-what-is-it/21521813#21521813?newreg=16984c920f3740cdba0bc782a34f360e).